# Why can you enter a comment against a deleted answer when you are not allowed to submit it?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, usability

I deleted an answer.  I decided to add a comment to it since the 'add comment' option was still shown.  I typed the comment and hit submit; only then did it say "You can't do that".  That is not a good user experience.  Don't display the 'add comment' option when it cannot be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This only happens if you *just* deleted the post. If you refresh the page, the link will be gone.

But I agree, the link should be gone regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is more instructive (i.e. it teaches people how the system works) to display a link and offer a message explaining why the link cannot be used under certain conditions, than it is to inexplicably display and hide the link in a manner that appears to be random.

Comment: You may disagree, but it's true. ;)  It's a basic fact of UI.

Comment: But then the error message should be shown as soon as you click the link, not only at submit after you spent the time to write the comment text.

Comment: @sth: You're right about that.